# AccessDeniedException when directory rights is not 777

Tags: java, linux

I run java application as user, who is the owner of the directory and the file

```
System.getProperty("user.name") == "wfadmin"

# ls -la /usr/WF/WF_PPRB/SSL/certs/ignite/
-rw-r----- 1 wfadmin   wfgroup     34 Dec 16 15:31 token.txt
-rw-r----- 1 wfadmin   wfgroup   2058 Oct  9 17:50 truststore.jks
# ls -la /usr/WF/WF_PPRB/SSL/certs/
drw-r----- 2 wfadmin   wfgroup   4096 Dec 16 15:31 ignite
```

But when i try to read file in java:

```
Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/usr/WF/WF_PPRB/SSL/certs/ignite/truststore.jks"))
```

I got AccessDeniedException

If i give rights 777 to directory /usr/WF/WF_PPRB/SSL/certs/ignite/, but truststore.jks still 640 - its work correctly

Comment: Accessing a directory on Linux requires the permission X/Execute to be set.

Comment: I did a search for "unix directory permissions" and was about to post the same information (first link): https://arc.ucar.edu/knowledge_base/68878469 *"flags to indicate who can list files in a directory (r), create and remove files in the directory (w), or cd into or traverse (x) the directory"*

Comment: And the two paths are not equal

Comment: Thank you! chmod +x solved problem

Comment: *AND* the poster seems to have omitted the directory `certs` from the code snippet, well spotted.  That might be a typo in the question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access a directory, you need to have the X/Execute/Traverse permission.